Possible to copy motion keyframes to multiple objects?
Here is simplified version of what I want to do:
I have a cube that translates along the Y-axis from frame 1 to frame 100, and it also scales along the z-axis, using keyframes.
Now I want to copy those exact same keyframes to a dozen other identical cubes which all have the same coordinates and scale values.
In After Effects (for instance) I would simply copy the keyframes from the one object and then paste them into all the others.  In Blender I can't figure out how to do that.
Would love some ideas, thanks!
